# Combine and sum two indexed arrays into one flat array

Tags: php, arrays, sum, merging-data

I need a new array combining 2 array with calculation.

```
$array1 = array(2,5,7,1);

$array2 = array(1,3,2,5);
```

result array should output

```
$array3 = array(3,8,9,6);
```

Is this possible in PHP? I know the `array_merge()` function combines two array, but how to combine after calculating the sum?

This is possible in C#, but I want to know how I can do it in PHP.

Comment: where is 3rd index in first array which content value 1 ?

Comment: Please Edit the question (the examples you gave seams to be wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are guaranteed to be matched in size then you can use something like this

```
$array3 = array();

for($x =0; $x<count($array1); $x++){
     $array3[] = $array1[$x] + $array2[$x];
}
```

If the arrays are not guaranteed to be of the same size you can do the following

```
$array3 = array();
$max = max(count($array1), count($array2));
for($x =0; $x<$max; $x++){
     $array3[] = (isset($array1[$x])?$array1[$x]:0)) + (isset($array2[$x])?$array2[$x]:0));
}
```

With the adoption of PHP 7 and it's [null coalesce operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#PHP) this code becomes much more readable:

```
$array3 = array();
$max = max(count($array1), count($array2));
for($x =0; $x<$max; $x++){
     $array3[] = ($array1[$x] ?? 0) + ($array2[$x] ?? 0);
}
```

Comment: @Orangepill what about my answer is not simpler?

Comment: @imsiso I think your's is going to result in the equivalent of an array merge (you will end up with 4 elements instead of the intended two) because the right hand side of your or will only be evaluated in the event that your left hand side returns false.

Answer (score 4):

For this you have to use [**foreach**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop

```
<?php
$array1 = array(2,5,7,1);
$array2 = array(1,3,2,5);
$array3= array();


foreach($array1 as $key=>$value)
{
   $array3[$key] = $array1[$key]+$array2[$key];
}

print_r($array3)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid writing a custom callback, you can transpose the two arrays values, then sum each set, but this will require two full cycles (not very performant). ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3aSqU))

```
var_export(array_map('array_sum', array_map(null, $array1, $array2))); // add as many arrays as you wish
```

Instead, iterate over both arrays synchronously and sum the "columns" (values occurring at the same position -- not necessarily the numeric key). ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qr8c9))

```
var_export(array_map(fn(...$col) => array_sum($col), $array1, $array2)); // add as many arrays as you wish
```

When you only have exactly two arrays, then `array_sum()` and the spread operator can be avoided by using individual variables in the custom function signature and the addition operator. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ufG3R))

```
var_export(array_map(fn($a, $b) => $a + $b, $array1, $array2));
```

---

To merely add `$array2`'s values to `$array1`'s values, iterate `$array1` and modify the values by reference. While looping use the addition-assignment "combined operator" to add the value from the second array to the corresponding value of the first array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dA2cC))

```
foreach ($array1 as $i => &$v) {
    $v += $array2[$i];
}
var_export($array1);
```

To populate a new array with the sums without affecting the input arrays, iterate one array and push the sum of the corresponding values from both arrays into a result array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sSOQh))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $i => $v) {
    $result[] = $v + $array2[$i];
}
var_export($result);
```